# Filter a dictionary based on key

Tags: ansible

I have a dict like this

```
{"product_1": [
        "account1",
        "account2"
    ],
"product_2": [
        "account1",
        "account2"
    ],
...
"product_10": [
        "account1",
        "account2"
    ]}
```

How to filter this dict based on the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are specific jinja2 filters for that: [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr) and [`rejectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#rejectattr).

But those work on a list of dicts, not on a dict itself. You will have to use [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) and [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) to work around that.

Here are some example usage:

```yaml
# Values are dicts, select only items with specific attribute defined.
result: "{{ my_dict | dict2items | selectattr('value.my_attribute', 'defined')
  | list | items2dict }}"

# Values are lists (as in your example), check for an existing item value.
result: "{{ my_dict | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'contains', 'some item')
  | list | items2dict }}"

# Values are dict. Reject elements when attributes has a specific value.
result: "{{ my_dict | dict2items | rejectattr('value.my_attribute', '==', 'Does not apply')
  | list | items2dict }}"
```

Check the above documentations and the rest of the [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) for an exhaustive view of all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `dict2items` to reformat the elements to have the names you are searching for as keys, then pass it to `map` filter to get those keys:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    myvar: 
      product_1:
      - account1
      - account2
      product_2:
      - account1
      - account2
      product_10:
      - account1
      - account2

    
  tasks:
  - name: extract the list of keys
    debug:
      msg: '{{ myvar | dict2items | map(attribute="key") | list }}'
```

cheers